# How to drop column according to NAN percentage for dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

For certain columns of `df`, if 80% of the column is `NAN`.

What's the simplest code to drop such columns?

Comment: something like `for col in df.columns: if sum(df[col].isnull())/float(len(df.index)) > 0.8: del df[col]` should help

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) for threshold and then remove columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` (because remove columns), also need invert condition - so `<.8` means remove all columns `>=0.8`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() < .8]
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df.loc[:80, 'A'] = np.nan
df.loc[:5, 'C'] = np.nan
df.loc[20:, 'D'] = np.nan

print (df.isnull().mean())
A    0.81
B    0.00
C    0.06
D    0.80
E    0.00
dtype: float64

df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() < .8]
print (df.head())
         B   C         E
0  0.278369 NaN  0.004719
1  0.670749 NaN  0.575093
2  0.209202 NaN  0.219697
3  0.811683 NaN  0.274074
4  0.940030 NaN  0.175410
```

If want remove columns by minimal values [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) working nice with parameter `thresh` and `axis=1` for remove columns:

```
np.random.seed(1997)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1], p=(0.8,0.2),size=(10,10)))
print (df)
     0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8    9
0  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
1  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
2  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN  NaN
3  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
4  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0
5  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0
6  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
7  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
8  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
9  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN

df1 = df.dropna(thresh=2, axis=1)
print (df1)
     0    3    4    5    7    9
0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
5  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
9  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

**EDIT: For non-Boolean data**

Total number of NaN entries in a column must be less than 80% of total entries:

```
 df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().sum() < 0.8*df.shape[0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df.dropna(thresh=np.int((100-percent_NA_cols_required)*(len(df.columns)/100)),inplace=True)
```

Basically pd.dropna takes number(int) of non_na cols required if that row is to be removed.

Comment: `df.dropna(thresh=int(ratio_nonNA *(len(df.columns))),inplace=True)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the pandas `dropna`. For example:

```
df.dropna(axis=1, thresh = int(0.2*df.shape[0]), inplace=True)
```

Notice that we used 0.2 which is 1-0.8 since the `thresh` refers to the number of non-NA values

Comment: I think with "thresh = int(0.8*df.shape[0])" you are saying to keep columns with at least 80% of non-Nan. The question was how to drop columns with at least 80% of Nan.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Many thanks. I edited it. The threshold is the "Require that many non-NA values."

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in comments, if you use `sum()` on a boolean test, you can get the number of occurences.

**Code:**

```
def get_nan_cols(df, nan_percent=0.8):
    threshold = len(df.index) * nan_percent
    return [c for c in df.columns if sum(df[c].isnull()) >= threshold]
```

**Used as:**

```
del df[get_nan_cols(df, 0.8)]
```

Comment: I also appreciate this approach because it's so evidently adaptable to a different decision threshold!