# Pandas select all columns without NaN

Tags: python, pandas, select, null

I have a DF with 200 columns. Most of them are with NaN's. I would like to select all columns with no NaN's or at least with the minimum NaN's. I've tried to drop all with a threshold or with notnull() but without success. Any ideas.

```
df.dropna(thresh=2, inplace=True)
df_notnull = df[df.notnull()]
```

DF for example:

```
col1  col2 col3
23     45  NaN
54     39  NaN
NaN    45  76
87     32  NaN
```

The output should look like:

```
 df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=2)

    col1  col2
    23     45  
    54     39  
    NaN    45  
    87     32
```

Comment: No data no use. Add sample data to illustrate your problem .

Comment: mate, you want me to add 200 columns to illustrate it NaN's? :)

Comment: You havent seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples. Adding sample data makes understand problem properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop column according to NAN percentage for dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311555/how-to-drop-column-according-to-nan-percentage-for-dataframe)

Comment: It is simple use `pd.isnull` with sum i.e `df.loc[:,pd.isnull(df).sum()<=2]`, adding sample data is always better :) And why are you not using `dropna`? Its giving you what you want right ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can create with non-NaN columns using

```
df = df[df.columns[~df.isnull().all()]]
```

Or

```
null_cols = df.columns[df.isnull().all()]
df.drop(null_cols, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

If you wish to remove columns based on a certain percentage of NaNs, say columns with more than 90% data as null

```
cols_to_delete = df.columns[df.isnull().sum()/len(df) > .90]
df.drop(cols_to_delete, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 13):

`df[df.columns[~df.isnull().any()]]` will give you a DataFrame with only the columns that have no null values, and should be the solution.

`df[df.columns[~df.isnull().all()]]` only removes the columns that have nothing but null values and leaves columns with even one non-null value.

**`df.isnull()`** will return a dataframe of booleans with the same shape as df. These bools will be True if the particular value is null and False if it isn't.

**`df.isnull().any()`** will return True for all columns with even one null. This is where I'm diverging from the accepted answer, as **`df.isnull().all()`** will not flag columns with even one value!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you wan't to get all the columns without any NaN. If that's the case, you can first get the name of the columns without any NaN using `~col.isnull.any()`, then use that your columns.

I can think in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [23, 54, pd.np.nan, 87],
    'col2': [45, 39, 45, 32],
    'col3': [pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 76, pd.np.nan,]
})

# This function will check if there is a null value in the column
def has_nan(col, threshold=0):
    return col.isnull().sum() > threshold

# Then you apply the "complement" of function to get the column with
# no NaN.

df.loc[:, ~df.apply(has_nan)]

# ... or pass the threshold as parameter, if needed
df.loc[:, ~df.apply(has_nan, args=(2,))]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Could you explain why is not a correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

### Here is a simple function which you can use directly by passing dataframe and threshold

```
df
'''
     pets   location     owner     id
0     cat  San_Diego     Champ  123.0
1     dog        NaN       Ron    NaN
2     cat        NaN     Brick    NaN
3  monkey        NaN     Champ    NaN
4  monkey        NaN  Veronica    NaN
5     dog        NaN      John    NaN
'''
```

---

```
def rmissingvaluecol(dff,threshold):
    l = []
    l = list(dff.drop(dff.loc[:,list((100*(dff.isnull().sum()/len(dff.index))>=threshold))].columns, 1).columns.values)
    print("# Columns having more than %s percent missing values:"%threshold,(dff.shape[1] - len(l)))
    print("Columns:\n",list(set(list((dff.columns.values))) - set(l)))
    return l


rmissingvaluecol(df,1) #Here threshold is 1% which means we are going to drop columns having more than 1% of missing values

#output
'''
# Columns having more than 1 percent missing values: 2
Columns:
 ['id', 'location']
'''
```

Now create new dataframe excluding these columns

```
l = rmissingvaluecol(df,1)
df1 = df[l]
```

**PS: You can change threshold as per your requirement**

### Bonus step

You can find the percentage of missing values for each column (optional)

```
def missing(dff):
    print (round((dff.isnull().sum() * 100/ len(dff)),2).sort_values(ascending=False))

missing(df)

#output
'''
id          83.33
location    83.33
owner        0.00
pets         0.00
dtype: float64
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try `df_notnull = df.dropna(how='all')`
This will get you only non null rows.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: Well you a right mate, with df_notnull = df.dropna(axis=1) I can select all columns which do not contain any NaN row value, but when I add thresh parameter still showing all columns :(

Answer (score 0):

```
null_series = df.isnull().sum() # The number of missing values from each column in your dataframe
full_col_series = null_series[null_series == 0] # Will keep only the columns with no missing values

df = df[full_col_series.index]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me quite well and probably tailored for your need as well!

```
def nan_weed(df,thresh):
ind = []
i = df.shape[1]
for j in range(0,i-1):
    if df[j].isnull().sum() <= thresh:
        ind.append(j)
return df[ind]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of how to get rid of null values on this thread. Which for my dataframes is never the case. We do not delete data. Ever.

I took the question as how to get just your null values to show, and in my case I had to find latitude and longitude and fill them in.

What I did was this ***for one column nulls***:

```
df[df['Latitude'].isnull()]
```

***or to explain it out***

```
dataframe[dataframe['Column you want'].isnull()]
```

This pulled up my whole data frame and all the missing values of latitude.

What did not work is this and I can't explain why. Trying to do ***two columns at the same time:***

```
df[df[['Latitude','Longitude']].isnull()]
```

That will give me all NANs in the entire data frame.

So to do this all at once what I added was the ID, in my case my ID for each row is APNs, with the two columns I needed at the end

```
df[df['Latitude'].isnull()][['APN','Latitude','Longitude']]
```

By doing this little hack I was able to get every ID I needed to add data too for 600,000+ rows of data to filter for. Then did it again for longitude just to be sure I did not miss anything.