# Drop Columns with more than 60 Percent of "empty" Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'c1': ['Test1','Test2','NULL','Test3',' ','Test4','Test4','Test1',"Test3"],
    'c2': [' ','Test1',' ','NULL',' ','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'],
    'c3': [0,0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0],
    'c4': ['NULL', 'Test2', 'Test1','Test1', 'Test2', 'Test2','Test1','Test1','Test2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    c1      c2      c3      c4
0   Test1           0       NULL
1   Test2   Test1   0       Test2
2   NULL            0       Test1
3   Test3   NULL    0       Test1
4                   0       Test2
5   Test4   NULL    1       Test2
6   Test4   NULL    5       Test1
7   Test1   NULL    0       Test1
8   Test3   NULL    0       Test2
```

I want to drop all columns, that have more than 60 % of "empty" values. "Empty" means in my case that the values are for example: ' ', 'NULL' or 0. There are strings (c1, c2, c4) as well as integers (c3).

The result should be a dataframe with columns c1 and c4 only.

```
    c1      c4
0   Test1   NULL
1   Test2   Test2
2   NULL    Test1
3   Test3   Test1
4           Test2
5   Test4   Test2
6   Test4   Test1
7   Test1   Test1
8   Test3   Test2
```

I have no idea how to handle that problem. Only thing that comes to my mind is something like

```
df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
```

to delete all columns where all values are 0, 'NULL' and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop column according to NAN percentage for dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311555/how-to-drop-column-according-to-nan-percentage-for-dataframe)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for check all formats and then get `mean` for treshold and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`:

```
print (df.isin([' ','NULL',0]))
      c1     c2     c3     c4
0  False   True   True   True
1  False  False   True  False
2   True   True   True  False
3  False   True   True  False
4   True   True   True  False
5  False   True  False  False
6  False   True  False  False
7  False   True   True  False
8  False   True   True  False

print (df.isin([' ','NULL',0]).mean())
c1    0.222222
c2    0.888889
c3    0.777778
c4    0.111111
dtype: float64

df = df.loc[:, df.isin([' ','NULL',0]).mean() < .6]
print (df)
      c1     c4
0  Test1   NULL
1  Test2  Test2
2   NULL  Test1
3  Test3  Test1
4         Test2
5  Test4  Test2
6  Test4  Test1
7  Test1  Test1
8  Test3  Test2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Trying your solution, I noticed, that there are also "real" empty cells. Therefore I added `df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() < .6]`. Is there a way to combine it with your code (`df = df.loc[:, df.isin([' ','NULL',0]).mean() < .6]`)?

Comment: @Krypt - my first idea is `df = df.loc[:, df.isin([' ','NULL',0, np.nan]).mean() < .6]`, but not tested. Can you check it?

Comment: @Krypt - I just test it by `data = {
    'c1': ['Test1','Test2',np.nan,'Test3',' ','Test4','Test4','Test1',"Test3"],
    'c2': [' ','Test1',' ','NULL',' ',np.nan,np.nan,'NULL',np.nan],
    'c3': [0,0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0],
    'c4': [np.nan, 'Test2', 'Test1','Test1', 'Test2', 'Test2','Test1','Test1','Test2']
}` and working nice.

Comment: thanks again. I should've mentioned that I already tried it with `np.nan` (like you just suggested). It worked fine for any isolated example, but unfortunately not for my specific application in RapidMiner. The only thing that worked to get rid of those columns was `df.isnull`. Therefore I was looking for any solution to combine those two statements (`df.isnull()` and `df.isin()`) in "one line".

Comment: @Krypt - So  give me a sec.

Comment: @Krypt - Please check `df = df.loc[:, (df.isin([' ','NULL',0]) | df.isnull()).mean() <= .6]`

Answer (score 21):

you can drop the columns using [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) `thresh` parameter:

```
In [58]: df = df.replace([0,' ','NULL'],np.nan)
In[59]: df
Out[59]: 
      c1     c2   c3     c4
0  Test1    NaN  NaN    NaN
1  Test2  Test1  NaN  Test2
2    NaN    NaN  NaN  Test1
3  Test3    NaN  NaN  Test1
4    NaN    NaN  NaN  Test2
5  Test4    NaN  1.0  Test2
6  Test4    NaN  5.0  Test1
7  Test1    NaN  NaN  Test1
8  Test3    NaN  NaN  Test2

In [60]: df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[0]*0.6,how='all',axis=1)
Out[60]: 
      c1     c4
0  Test1    NaN
1  Test2  Test2
2    NaN  Test1
3  Test3  Test1
4    NaN  Test2
5  Test4  Test2
6  Test4  Test1
7  Test1  Test1
8  Test3  Test2
```

Comment: Threshold is defined as 'Require that many non-NA values'. So in this example, we may need to keep thresh=df.shape[0]*0.4

Comment: I think `df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[0]*0.6,how='all',axis=1)` will return an error: `TypeError: You cannot set both the how and thresh arguments at the same time.`

Answer (score 4):

Below given solution is very small and fast(in performance)

> Step:1
> we are finding percentage of null value in every column

> Step:2
> we are finding column names in list having more than 60% null values

> Step:3
> Drop columns having more than 60% null values

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'c1': ['Test1','Test2','NULL','Test3',' ','Test4','Test4','Test1',"Test3"],
    'c2': [' ','Test1',' ','NULL',' ','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'],
    'c3': [0,0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0],
    'c4': ['NULL', 'Test2', 'Test1','Test1', 'Test2', 'Test2','Test1','Test1','Test2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Below code gives percentage of null in every column
null_percentage = df.isnull().sum()/df.shape[0]*100

# Below code gives list of columns having more than 60% null
col_to_drop = null_percentage[null_percentage>60].keys()

output_df = df.drop(col_to_drop, axis=1)
```