# How can I delete a row if a certain amount of values are missing?

Tags: python, pandas, row, delete-row

I have the following dataset:

```
      A     B     C     D
0  0.46  0.23   NaN  0.41
1  0.65  0.48  0.07  0.15
2   NaN  1.00  0.79  0.09
3  0.50  0.97  0.07  0.55
4  0.45  0.44  0.23  0.41
5   NaN  0.39   NaN  0.31
6  0.32  0.87  0.73  0.57
7  0.82  0.67  0.73  0.19
8  0.65   NaN   NaN  0.81
9  0.36  0.23  1.00  0.51
```

I would like to delete rows in which there are 2 or more values missing (or specify as more than 50% missing?), therefore I would like to delete rows 5 and 8 and get the following output:

```
      A     B     C     D
0  0.46  0.23   NaN  0.41
1  0.65  0.48  0.07  0.15
2   NaN  1.00  0.79  0.09
3  0.50  0.97  0.07  0.55
4  0.45  0.44  0.23  0.41
6  0.32  0.87  0.73  0.57
7  0.82  0.67  0.73  0.19
9  0.36  0.23  1.00  0.51
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df.dropna(thresh=3)` Will do what you want.

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311824/5916727

Comment: In your case, you may need to specify axis, something like `df[df.isnull().mean(axis=1) < 0.5]`