# For loop to drop columns based on null values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a data frame called lc. And in the shape of the data frame is (235607,146)
I was able to write a code that shows me the percentage of null values in each column(`np.sum(lc.isnull())/lc.shape[0]*100`). And now I need help in writing a for loop that drops all the columns with null values greater than 70 percent

Comment: can you share the code snippet ?

Comment: You should almost never use a loop to modify a DataFrame. You are most likely trying to solve your problem incorrectly.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: What kind of data are you working with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop column according to NAN percentage for dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311555/how-to-drop-column-according-to-nan-percentage-for-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boolean` indexing. Taken `mean` to check the percent of null values in each column. As `false` will be returned in case of columns that don't meet the criteria, they will not be shotlisted.

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[:,df.isin([0,' ',np.nan,None]).mean()<0.7]
```