# Discard more than 25% missing data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with more than 30K lines. Some of these lines contain NA values and I would like to discard the one that have more than 25% missing value. I have tried with the pandas command dropna() but I can only use the command "any" or "all". Which line of code should I use to discriminate for the lines with more than 25% missing value?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop column according to NAN percentage for dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311555/how-to-drop-column-according-to-nan-percentage-for-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Update: one line answer based on [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311555/how-to-drop-column-according-to-nan-percentage-for-dataframe):

```py
df = df[ df.isna().mean(axis=1) <= 0.25 ]
```

---

Assuming that you have this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    keep=dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4),
    drop=dict(a=None, b=None, c=10, d=20),
    keep_2=dict(a=None, b=4, c=2, d=1),
    drop_2=dict(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None)
)).T
```

You can calculate the number of empty values in row using `df.isna().sum(axis=1)`. Axis 1 used to show that you adding items in rows, instead of columns. Then you can check what rows have more that 25% of nans and select all the rest:

```py
NANS_THRESHOLD = 0.25

nans_count_in_line = df.isna().sum(axis=1)
total_columns = len(df.columns)
is_too_many_nans = nans_count_in_line / total_columns > NANS_THRESHOLD

df[ ~is_too_many_nans ]
```

Result:

```
        a   b   c   d
keep    1   2   3   4
keep_2  NaN 4   2   1
```

Comment: Hi ZTEP, I am trying to use your code but I could not make it work with my file. I got this error "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!". Basically, I copy paste your code but instead of the dict I do use my file df = pd.DataFrame('input_file.csv').T

Comment: Hi @patadu, this is strange, works fine for me. What pandas version are you using? You can find it out calling `pd.__version__`

Comment: I do have version 1.0.1

Comment: Oh, I understand what's the matter, I misunderstood your first comment. If you want to load dataframe from csv file, you should use `pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')`. Also you don't need to call `.T` method, this is `.transpose()` method, used to reconstruct dataframe, that I used in my example

Comment: Yes, I can use `pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')` but after that I have to select lines with a more that 25% NaN values and delete from the file. I have been trying with other codes but I could not make it

Comment: Can you read file, delete lines with more than 25% NaN values and save this file using `pd.to_csv`? Would it solve your problem?

Comment: No, that's my problem, How do I select for line with more that 25% missing values and remove them?

Comment: Does the code suggested in my solution works for you? If not, is there some kind of error? Also, there are great one line solution linked by @AMC (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311555/how-to-drop-column-according-to-nan-percentage-for-dataframe): `df = df[ df.isna().mean(axis=1) <= 0.25 ]`

Comment: Nope, it does not give me any error but at the same time when I check it, all the values are still there. I have tried also with some other code but I do always get the same amount of lines.

Comment: How do you check how many lines are left in your dataframe? Are you checking csv file? Could you provide an example of your data with rows that have missing values?

Comment: `import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')
df.dropna(thresh=140, axis=0)
df.tail(50)`

Comment: I do not see discarding missing data line in your code. Did you tried `import pandas as pd`
`df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')`
`df.dropna(thresh=140, axis=0)`
`df = df[ df.isna().mean(axis=1) <= 0.25 ]`
`df.tail(50)`?

Comment: In the end I think yes, I have used another command and I did get blank lines in the excel file and later removed them